# Tuple in IN clause in MS Access 2003

Tags: sql, ms-access, tuples, ms-access-2003, row-value-expression

I wanted to make a query in **MS Access 2003** (or just sql in VBA) which would have an **IN** clause working on **tuples**, i.e.,

I have to columns with **year** and **month**, and I would like to extract for example 2010-10 and 2012-03 using **IN** clause. For comparison in Postgres it would look like

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (year, month) IN (("2010","10"),("2012","03"));
```

but it does not work for me in Access. Yes, I store both year and month as **text**, but it really does not matter.

I know I could write it using many **AND** and **OR**, or make a **LEFT JOIN** with a temporary table. But those queries are created prograYmatically, so I wanted to make it as simple as possible.

Comment: If you replace double quotes with single quotes then your SQL complies with the SQL:2000 standard. Sadly, Access is not compliant with even entry level SQL:2000 and the syntax is not supported ([it isn't supported on SQL Server](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/299231/add-support-for-ansi-standard-row-value-constructors) either).

Comment: ...however, I think you have a design problem. You seem to be modelling the period of one month using two attributes of type 'text'. Consider using temporal data types instead, perhaps coupled with a [Calendar table](http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html) but hard to give good advice based on a single query ;)

Comment: There was not much designed. It was a fast task where I needed to create a query which worked like above. Of course I could import everything to Postgres, but it takes longer to create a table etc. than to import the file to Access Hence, I wanted to know if it was possible to make this kind of WHERE clouse.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE year & month IN ("201010","201203")
```

Comment: Good workaround, and it works regardless of the type of **year** & **month** I mean they may be both **numbers** or **text**.

Comment: Just note that this syntax does not allow for index usage.

Comment: The OP wishes to use IN, an indexed search will not be possible with that condition.